# Trying to be honest in a hiring process without over-complicating

Tags: hiring-process

I'm in a hiring process where I have **8 hours** to build a project.

The project is split in two parts of 4 hours. I have finished the first part last week, and I will meet with my technical interviewer tomorrow to review it and see if I will be moving on to the second part or not.

However, since I had a lot of free time, I've branched the first phase of the project and worked on it a couple days on a local environment. This means I have a high quality project to deliver for phase two, but I have spent a lot more than 4 hours on it.

It is **important** for them that **I spend the time correctly**, so they can see how fast I can write code.

To solve some of the problems of the project I had to research for some time. I wouldn't be able to solve them in 4 hours, and I don't want to pass an impression of seniority that I don't have.

I'll be meeting with my interviewing manager tomorrow and I don't know if I should mention any of it, what do you think?

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish by not telling them?

Comment: If it is really, really important for them to see if you spend 4 hours and no more, chances are they will ask

Answer (score 6):

Represent your work done in 4 hours, and mention and preview your improvements to the project, including the additional time needed to do that. If they value your improvements and like the speed, it will improve your chances. If not, they will skip that part. It is important to remember that you should focus on reviewing the first part. If they like your work, they will ask about it.